# Does "Find Steed" work with proficicently to ride Warhorses?

Tags: dnd-5e

Does "Find Steed" spell work if my PC is proficient and trained to ride Warhorse and can I add Horseshoes of Zephyr or any magical items?

Comment: I don't understand the question - why would you assume it wouldn't?

Comment: this may be a partial duplicate of https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/90632/37348 if he is asking about having the "find steed" have gear

Comment: I think that the question is asking if proficiency with a Warhorse would apply to a Warhorse summoned by "Find Steed" (seeing as how being proficient wouldn't impose a negative aspect to spell casting ability).  Is that a correct reading of the question?

Answer (score 2):

The [Basic Rules](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Find%20Steed#content) description of "Find Steed" contains this

> You summon a spirit that assumes the form of an unusually intelligent, strong, and loyal steed, creating a long-lasting bond with it. Appearing in an unoccupied space within range, the steed takes on a form that you choose: **a warhorse**, a pony, a camel, an elk, or a mastiff. (Your GM might allow other animals to be summoned as steeds.) The steed has the statistics of the chosen form, though it is a celestial, fey, or fiend (your choice) instead of its normal type.

*emphasis mine*

This says that one of the forms the steed can take is a Warhorse. For all intents and purposes (game statistics) it is whatever form it takes, except for its type, which would be celestial, fey, or fiend instead of beast.  So proficiency and training with a Warhorse would work

As for attaching gear to the steed, it can be done but may not persist if the steed is "killed" or "dismissed" see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/90632/37348) for more details

Comment: @mattdm thanks I wasn't sure how much I should put since I have an account with Roll20 and am not to sure if everything I see on them is SRD.