# Can my paladin's steed carry stuff?

Tags: dnd-5e, mount, encumbrance

One of the paladin spells is [Find Steed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-steed), which summons a spirit taking the form of a steed. Can it carry my party's stuff, like a regular animal can?

Comment: Related on [When a creature summoned through find steed is dismissed or killed, what happens to barding, saddle, and saddlebags?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/90632/when-a-creature-summoned-through-find-steed-is-dismissed-or-killed-what-happens)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes

It is just another creature, and creatures can carry things. It doesn't come with anything other than itself when you summon it, so if you want anything else, you'll need to buy it and put it on yourself.

As for specific carrying capacity, please see the stat block for the creature and the [rules on lifting and carrying](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#LiftingandCarrying).

### My table allowed the steed to generally carry certain things even when dismissed.

We generally hand wave a lot of the mount rules to simplify control and management at the table (acts on players turn and is fully controlled by player.) There are times when the DM stepped in to say "NO" to some things, but that's about it.

In terms of items, I worked with my DM to determine what it would "always-have" and what it wouldn't. Once agreed, it was agreed and we just moved forward.

Comment: "It doesn't come with anything other than itself" so you'd say I need to supply a saddle and things? What about when it is a different form? Do I need to go get a different saddle? It would make sense to me if the bare minimum to make it easily ridable. Or is that not needed due to the bond between the paladin and the animal?

Comment: I realize this isn't the original question, but this discussion has brought up stuff I never thought of. Perhaps I should re-ask

Comment: @jonnybolton16 You'd need to supply whatever your DM tells you you need. But RAW, it comes with nothing. So if you summon a different form, then the saddle would no longer fit unless you've got a magical saddle (and if your DM allows said magical saddle to fit a new form.)

Comment: @jonnybolton16 While I generally dislike the 'there are no hidden rules', this is a case where it applies. Things do what they say. If you want something specific and it doesn't say it, you'll need to talk with your DM. If you'd like to chat more, you can always hop into [chat] to discuss anything more general or if you want to go over things before posting a question.