# What is the AC of a sprite familiar (from the Find Familiar spell) if it is dismissed to a pocket dimension and then caused to reappear as an action?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, equipment, familiars, armor-class

The [most recent Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=17) erratas the [*find familiar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) spell so that familiars are now stripped naked when dismissed to a pocket dimension.  The Pact of the Chain warlock can summon a [Sprite](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/sprite) familiar; when initially summoned, it is wearing leather armor, which its statblock lists as the source of its armor class.

Is there a system in place for calculating what the AC is if the warlock dismisses the sprite to a pocket dimension, and then later causes the sprite to reappear as an action?

It looks like using the formula for player characters in leather armor (11 + Dex), would be consistent with the published Dexterity, but we know that the rest of the sprite's equipment (longsword, longbow) work differently because it's a monster, so I'd prefer DM-facing monster adjustment rules for this.

Comment: The sprite is also naked when originally summoned.

Comment: @J.A.Streich It's not, though.

Comment: Note: the Sage Advice Compendium is not errata. Errata are changes to the rules; the SAC lists official rulings (i.e. interpretations of the rules). Also, as noted in my comment on the answer, the question mischaracterizes the exact wording of the SAC ruling. I'd suggest that if you're going to focus on a strictly literalist interpretation of the rules (or, in this case, a strictly literalist interpretation of an official *ruling*), as [your other question suggests is the intent](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/176195/33569), you should probably just quote what the ruling specifically says.

Comment: ...Also, your question's claim about the formula for player characters' unarmored AC (without features that specifically modify it) is wrong; it should be 10 + Dex mod, not 11 + Dex mod. (I've also edited the question title to match what you ask in the body of the post; the original title of "What is a sprite familiar's AC?" was much broader than the specific scenario you ask about in the body of the post.)

Comment: Your related question: [Does the Flock of Familiars spell produce endless sellable equipment for Sprites, in the same manner as the Find Familiar spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/176195/33569) Also related: [Are Sprite familiars from the Find Familiar spell summoned with the equipment listed in their statblock?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/176246/33569), [Can I use my familiar from the Find Familiar spell as a safety deposit box?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/61979/33569)

Comment: @V2Blast while the sage advice compendium may claim to clarify rather than change rules, it actually does the latter about as often as the former.  there's no primary source rule for 5e, so as far as I can tell it gets to do that.  I understand that there are separate documents called errata, but I don't think it is wrong or misleading to say the compendium erratas things.  If you'd like I could say 'changes the published rules to now officially say' instead, though; that would avoid the term while communicating what the document is.  I'm not sure if that would be clearer, though.

Comment: "I don't think it is wrong or misleading to say the compendium erratas things." - It is indeed. If you said the SAC's rulings sometimes aren't supported by what the rules (currently) state, you'd be right (e.g. if they describe designer *intent* that isn't matched by the rules) - but the SAC still isn't errata. In this case, the SAC ruling explicitly says: "No, the intent of *find familiar* is that any objects are left behind when the familiar vanishes. **This intent will be reflected in future printings of the *Player’s Handbook*.**" When that change happens, that's when it'll be errata.

Comment: @V2Blast note that the answer in that sentence is 'no' and the question asks 'does x happen'.  if it was just 'we didn't mean it to work that way' the answer would be 'yes, but', which it is not.  so there's a clear intent to change things presently/retroactively in the immediate sense, not just in theoretical future printings.

Comment: @Pleasestopbeingevil: This is why I advise against trying to overanalyze rulings rather than rules. :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### An unarmoured sprite has an AC of 14

I'm taking your ruling that sprites reappear without armour as read. For that discussion see:
[Are Sprite familiars from the Find Familiar spell summoned with the equipment listed in their statblock?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/176246/52137). For that matter this is equally applicable if the sprites doffs the armour or should the armour be destroyed.

The general rule for monster AC is given in the *Monster Manual* introduction (p. 7; emphasis added):

> A monster that wears armor or carries a shield has an Armor Class (AC) that takes its armor, shield, and Dexterity into account. *Otherwise, a monster's AC is based on its Dexterity modifier* and natural armor, if any. If a monster has natural armor, wears armor, or carries a shield, this is noted in parentheses after its AC value.

and similarly in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* under *Step 7. Armor Class* of *Creating a Monster Stat Block* (p. 276):

> A monster that doesn't wear armor might have natural armor, in which case it has an AC equal to 10 + its Dexterity modifier + its natural armor bonus.

Excepting the natural armour bonus, this identical to the PHB unarmoured AC (p. 14) of 10 + Dex modifier.

A sprite has no natural armour bonus (or has one of +0) thus has an AC of 10 + its Dex modifier of +4 = 14.

Comment: I think it's also worth noting that the SAC doesn't say "familiars are now stripped naked when de-summoned". Specifically, it says: "**When you dismiss the familiar you conjure with the *find familiar* spell to its pocket dimension, can it take any objects it’s wearing or carrying with it?** No, the intent of *find familiar* is that any objects are left behind when the familiar vanishes. This intent will be reflected in future printings of the *Player’s Handbook*." Up to you whether you want to speculate about intent, but I suspect this relates more to objects not listed in its statblock.

Comment: Following on from my previous comment, the question title currently just asks what a sprite familiar's AC is without any elaboration, but the body of the post asks "what the AC is if the warlock desummons and then later resummons the sprite" (i.e. dismisses it to a pocket dimension, and causes it to reappear). As a result, the latter seems like the primary question - and I've edited the question title accordingly - so the answer should explicitly indicate whether the querent's assumption about the sprite reappearing without armor is correct.

Comment: @V2Blast Added a note about taking that ruling as read (ie. as a DM's ruling for their table) and linked to the question which covers the SAC ruling on it.