# Can a wizard copy spells from another's spellbook?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wizard

Supposing either a wizard acquires and deciphers the spellbook of a slain enemy, or an ally shows him an unfamiliar one — could the wizard copy said spell for his own use rather than from a spell scroll?

Comment: related, about *preparing* but touches on copying: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/65369/23970

Comment: Related: [Will enemies with Wizard spells have spellbooks a PC Wizard can learn from?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55228/will-enemies-with-wizard-spells-have-spellbooks-a-pc-wizard-can-learn-from?s=19|1.2887)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Yes.

See PHB p.114, "Your Spellbook." This sidebar describes all of the conditions necessary for copying a spell into your spellbook. None of the requirements  (time, money, level) care about the storage medium of the spell you found.