# For the purposes of Magic Jar, does a monster with the Spellcasting special trait have class levels?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, class, traits

The spell *magic jar* says with regards to the creature who's body the caster is possessing:

> If the target has any class levels, you can't use any of its class features.

The [only class feature a monster can usually have is Spellcasting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/148424/41726), which is usually worded like (**emphasis** mine):

> The [monster] is an Xth-level **spellcaster**. Its spellcasting ability is [Ability] (spell save DC X, +X to hit with spell attacks). The [monster] has the following [class] spells prepared

Nothing directly seems to imply that such a monster has "class levels". Do they?

If not, and by extension the possessor would keep the Spellcasting special trait, would the caster of *magic jar* now have spells and spell slots from their Spellcasting class feature *and* from the monster's Spellcasting?

Comment: Related on the usage of "spellcaster level": [What does “a spellcaster level” mean applying to monsters?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/158232/41726)